# PySpark : Use of aggregate function for complex query

Tags: apache-spark, aggregate-functions, pyspark

Suppose you have a dataframe with 3 columns which are numeric - like:

```
>>> df.show()
+-----------+---------------+------------------+--------------+---------------------+
|         IP|            URL|num_rebuf_sessions|first_rebuffer|num_backward_sessions|
+-----------+---------------+------------------+--------------+---------------------+
|10.45.12.13| ww.tre.com/ada|              1261|           764|                 2043|
|10.54.12.34|www.rwr.com/yuy|              1126|           295|                 1376|
|10.44.23.09|www.453.kig/827|              2725|           678|                 1036|
|10.23.43.14|www.res.poe/skh|              2438|           224|                 1455|
|10.32.22.10|www.res.poe/skh|              3655|           157|                 1838|
|10.45.12.13|www.453.kig/827|              7578|            63|                 1754|
|10.45.12.13| ww.tre.com/ada|              3854|           448|                 1224|
|10.34.22.10|www.rwr.com/yuy|              1029|           758|                 1275|
|10.54.12.34| ww.tre.com/ada|              7341|            10|                  856|
|10.34.22.10| ww.tre.com/ada|              4150|           455|                 1372|
+-----------+---------------+------------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

With schema being

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- IP: string (nullable = true)
 |-- URL: string (nullable = true)
 |-- num_rebuf_sessions: long (nullable = false)
 |-- first_rebuffer: long (nullable = false)
 |-- num_backward_sessions: long (nullable = false)
```

**Question**
I am interested in finding a complex query aggregation - like say `(sum(num_rebuf_sessions) - sum(num_backward_sessions)) * 100 / sum(first_rebuffer)`

How do I do it programmatically? 
The query aggregation can be anything which is provided as a input (assume a xml file or a json file)

**Note:**
1. In interpreter, I can run the complete statement like

```
>>> df.groupBy(keyList).agg((((func.sum('num_rebuf_sessions') - func.sum('first_rebuffer')) * 100)/func.sum('num_backward_sessions')).alias('Result')).show()
+-----------+---------------+------------------+
|         IP|            URL|            Result|
+-----------+---------------+------------------+
|10.54.12.34|www.rwr.com/yuy|263.70753561548884|
|10.23.43.14|www.453.kig/827| 278.7099317601011|
|10.34.22.10| ww.tre.com/ada|187.53939800299088|
+-----------+---------------+------------------+
```

2. But programmatically, it would take only a `dict` or a `list of column` which would mean tough to achieve the above functionality.

So is the `pyspark.sql.context.SQLContext.sql` only option left? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: As I know... Yes... You have to use these functions to solve your problem. OR, you can convert to RDD. Are you familiar with RDD?

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim : Yes, But RDD would make the operations much slower, compared to Dataframe (AFAIK). So was looking for an option in Dataframe itself. Which is better (in terms of performance?) RDD vs DataFrame complete SQL query?

Comment: Wondering why this question was downvoted!!!!

Comment: That wasn't me haha. So you are right, the dataFrame is much faster according this type of data you have. Well, I'm not able to find a better solution for this problem...

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim How would converting to RDD solve the problem?

Comment: @kumar_m_kiran This question is way to broad for SO. You can define a domain specific language that can be used to define queries, create lexer and parser and compile results to Python structure that can be passed to `agg`. It is not a rocket science but takes a lot of work.

Comment: It is not a big move... But is not efficient at all. It takes at least 3 times of the process of the DataFrame.